# Why is there a green bomber in Dyna Blaster multiplayer?

Tags: dos, bomberman

In Dyna Blaster, there is a multiplayer mode. Regardless of how many players are playing, the leaderboard on the top of the screen shows scores for 5 players. However, in the match setup screen, you can only set 2-4 players. Also, in the settings, you can set up controls for up to 2 keyboard and 2 joystick players. There is no fifth. Then why is there a fifth, green player on the leaderboard?

[image: Dyna Blaster multiplayer screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest way to answer this question is that the green bomber is actually playable in the Amiga version (and probably in other versions as well). A 5-player game would look as follows:

[image: Dyna Blaster on Amiga]

[image: Dyna Blaster on Amiga]

It is most likely that the developers were unable to have 5-player support for the MS-DOS version, but left the green bomber icon in the top bar anyway.